# How to address the return value of a register

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, x86-64

I am currently developing a simple kernel for a university course, in which I am asked to implement a function  that outputs all the register values. So far, I have managed to write the following:

```
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    pushState

    push rsi
    push rdi
    push rdx


    mov rcx, 5
    mov rdx, raxMsg
    mov rsi, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    call sysCallDispatcher

    mov rcx, 16
    mov rdx, [rax]
    mov rsi, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    call sysCallDispatcher

    pop rdx
    pop rdi
    pop rsi

    popState
    leave
    ret
```

This is just an example for the RAX register (raxMsg is defined as "RAX: " and sysCallDispatcher manages the syscall to output a write syscall).
My question is: when I load what is in RAX, what type of variable is being stored in rdx? Is it an int I have to convert to string?
Thank you.

Comment: `mov rdx, [rax]` loads the 8 bytes starting from the address stored in `rax`, interpreted as a little-endian quadword

Comment: "Type" is a high-level language concept. Registers just have bits. What they represent is a matter of how they are used. The function sysCallDispatcher() probably expects something to be in DX--look at its documentation.

Comment: If your system call returns a pointer in RAX, that makes sense.  Otherwise, if you want to print the original RAX value, you'll need to push / pop it around the first system call.  And yes, unless you have a "system call" that formats numbers into strings for you, you'll have to do that yourself.  [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) shows the algorithm, and x86-64 code to do so, including a Linux `write` system call.